# jQuery Mobile is not reloading my page properly

Tags: jquery-mobile

Ok, this is odd:
First I open page1.html. From page1.html I go to page2.html by link and then back to page1.html via another link.  These links are just regular links with relative path and not `rel="back"` kind of link.

Problem is: jQuery Mobile will cache page1.html (though it doesn't cache page2.html)
If I add rel="external" to the link of page2.html then the page1 is refresh, but together, all resources is also reloaded (which not what I want).

I only want the html of page1.html to be reloaded. I added `data-cache=false` and `data-dom-cache=false` to page1.html annotation but it doesn't help.

How can I have jQuery Mobile not caching page1.html with the given scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I am using a workarround that manualy removes the page based on the data-dom-cache attribute.  You need to add an event handler for **pagehide** events and check for the **domCache** property of the page data

```
$(document).on('pagehide', function(event, ui){
          var page = $(event.target);
          var pageData = page.data(); // get all the data attributes (remove the data prefix and format to camel case)
          if(pageData.domCache == false){
              console.log("Removing Page (id: " + page.attr('id') + ", url: " + pageData.url + ")"); //Log to console for debugging
              page.remove(); // remove the page
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works great. I wonder why the functionality is not included by default...